# What is "Syntax of Expression"

Tags: c

I am reading *The C Programming Language* written by **K&R** and I am stuck on a statement which says something about declarations:

> The syntax of the declaration for a variable mimics the syntax of expressions in which the variable might appear.

[image]

This is what I have understood from the above statement:

*When we declare a variable (e.g. `int a`), it means that when that identifier (`a`) is used in an expression, it will return a value of the specified type (`int`).*

Am I correct? And what is actually meant by *syntax of expression*?

Comment: "In mathematics, syntax refers to the rules governing the behavior of mathematical systems, such as formal languages used in logic." [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax)

Comment: *Am I correct?* Technically yes, but you are covering only the trivial case that wouldn't be worth of a special rule of its own. The rule becomes interesting and non-trivial when a declaration involves pointers, arrays, functions, and combinations thereof.

Comment: Expression here is *ip varable is ip.

Comment: @n.m. That's a very strange definition. Syntax governs form, not behaviour.

Comment: @EJP Behaviour is directly derived from form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's look at a few examples.

With

```
int *A;
```

you can use `*A` in an expression and it will have type `int`, so `A` must be a pointer to `int`.

With

```
int A[100];
```

you can use `A[i]` in an expression and it will have type `int`, so `A` must be an array of `int`.

But you can construct more complex declarations:

With

```
int (((A)));
```

you can use `(((A)))` in an expression and it will have type `int`, so `A` must be an `int`.

With

```
int *A[100];
```

you can use `*A[i]` in an expression and it will have type `int`, so `A` ...

- must be an array ...
- and its elements must be pointers to `int`

so `A` must be an array of pointers to `int`.

Similarly, with

```
int (*A)[100];
```

you can use `(*A)[i]` in an expression and it will have type `int`, so `A` ...

- must be a pointer ...
- and the thing it's pointing to must be an array of `int`

so `A` must be a pointer to an array of `int`.

---

This is what is meant by "*the syntax of the declaration for a variable mimics the syntax of expressions*": When you declare a variable, you write a sort of mini-expression whose result type is given, and by reasoning backwards, you can deduce the type of the variable being declared.

Comment: I'm not convinced the `(((A)))` example is worthy of inclusion, but the rest is good.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's meant to illustrate that declarators are like expressions in that arbitrary (even redundant) parentheses are allowed.

Comment: please explain it little bit what you mean by in an expression? and "(((A))) in an expression and it will have type int", then how A must be an int?

Comment: The original pointer to function notation also agrees: `double (*fun)(double) = sin; double d = (*fun)(2.1);` — that demonstrates the 'declaration matches usage syntax' meme.  OTOH, standard C now allows `double d = fun(2.1);`, though I still show my antiquity by preferring the explicit notation.  Also, pointers to functions may be beyond someone struggling with this concept in the first place.

Comment: @Bhaskar `2` is an expression of type `int`. `(2)` is also an expression of type `int`, and so is `(((2)))`. You can use arbitrary parentheses around values. The same applies to variables: If `(x)` has type `int`, then so has `x`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If you want to be fully explicit, you need `... = &sin`, too. :-)

Comment: Not really; AFAICR, the `&` wasn't allowed in pre-standard C.  (K&R 1st Edn, p115 says: _`strcmp`, `numcmp` and `swap` are addresses of functions; since they are known to be functions, the `&` operator is not necessary, in the same way that it is not necessary before an array name.  The compiler arranges for the address of the function to be passed._  The use of `*funcname` or `**funcname` etc is even more aberrant.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, that's just inconsistent.

Comment: @melpomene One last doubt what is mean by this "by reasoning backwards, you can deduce the type of the variable being declared"